# CNContactStore executeSaveRequest fails with error (CSIndexErrorDomain Code=-1005)

Tags: ios, ios9, contacts, cncontactstore

I am getting a CSIndexErrorDomain Code=-1005 when attempting to executeSaveRequest in the XCode 7.1 iPad 2 Simulator with the following code:

```
let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()  
saveRequest.addContact(newContact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)  

if let group = self.group {  
  saveRequest.addMember(newContact, toGroup: group)  
}  


try store.executeSaveRequest(saveRequest)
```

I have read that this is a CoreSpotlight error and that CoreSpotlight is not available on iPad, so why is the iOS 9 Contacts framework attempting to run CoreSpotlight API calls?

How can I avoid this error when saving a contact in iOS 9 or how can I catch it in particular, as opposed to a general catchall?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: Hello! You have found a solution to your problem?